# How can I create a video file from 35mm film shot with a motion picture camera?

Tags: after-effects, editing, adobe, adobe-media-encoder

I use a 35mm motion film camera to shoot some scenes of my productions.

The area of the images shot by the camera, when scanned at around 4k, is roughly 3648 x 2862. It can also be 2214 x 1712 but I prefer to make a higher quality file.

All images are scanned RAW, and I usually drop them as a 15fps sequence in After Effects. Ordering them into an animated sequence is the easy part, but exporting is more difficult.

When I export as **Lossless** from After Effects CS6, the file doesn't play on any other devices or plays very slowly and is huge (but the frames look decent, the grain is not too badly damaged by compression).

When I export with **H.264** codecs from After Effects, however, parts of the image's edges are randomly clipped in the exported file.

I tried exporting as **Lossless** .mov from AE, then converting to one of the profiles in AME called HD 1080i 25 (1.33 PAR), but this step either adds black bars randomly, creates a file I cannot play on recent devices, or compresses the image and the result looks very poor.

**How can I export a sequence of a pixel size and frame rate that I defined, without losing quality, the resulting file not being playable of having parts of the image cut off?**